# Delayed Job not logging in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I want my delayed job "code" to log in a different log file for business requirements. So I log a custom status in a log called as dj.log. Inside the "serialized" job, I am putting the log statements to log in my file.

Here is how the setup is

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 10
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !( Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development? ) #dont use delayed_job in development or test mode

#Delayed_job custom logger
DJ_LOGFILE = File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'dj.log')
```

and here is the job that the workers actually do

```
    people.each {|p| Mailer.mail(1233, p).deliver; sent_to << p.email }                
    Logger.new(DJ_LOGFILE).info("[DELIVERED] All Emails delivered (#{sent_to.join(", ")})")
```

what could be the problem here ? please help

Comment: the mails are getting delivered but the message is not getting logged

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DelayedJob` maintains it's own logger so you'll need to point that to your specific log file. So, in your initializer file (either environment.rb or, better, a specific `delayed_job.rb` file in `config/initializers`) add the following:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'dj.log'))
```

Comment: my code works well in development and staging environments well!

Comment: it seems that any file pointer points to DelayedJob::Worker.logger (defualt Rails.logger) http://groups.google.com/group/delayed_job/browse_thread/thread/5c13d59aa4f5cb41   so.. the above code worked for me!

Comment: For better logging in production, use `Delayed::Worker.logger ||= Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job_production.log'), 10, 100*1024*1024)`  to auto rotate the log files 100MB each, keeping 10 latest entries.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution (tested with `2.1.4`):

**config/initializers/delayed_job.rb**

```
Delayed::Worker.logger ||= Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this bug: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/382
.
.
.
.
.