# Logging in delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, delayed-job, clockwork

I can't get any log output from `delayed_job`, and I'm not sure my jobs are starting.

Here's my Procfile:

```
web:     bundle exec rails server
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
worker:  bundle exec clockwork app/clock.rb
```

And here's the job:

```
class ScanningJob
  def perform
    logger.info "logging from delayed_job"
  end

  def after(job)
    Rails.logger.info "logging from after delayed_job"
  end
end
```

I see that clockwork outputs to system out, and I can see worker executor starting, but I never see my log statements hit. I tried `puts` as well to no avail.

My clock file is pretty simple:

```
every(3.seconds, 'refreshlistings') { Delayed::Job.enqueue ScanningJob.new }
```

I just want to see this working, and lack of logging means I can't. What's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delayed\_job not logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507765/delayed-job-not-logging)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

When I needed log output from Delayed Jobs, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183676/delayed-job-not-logging-in-production) to be fairly helpful.

In `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` I add the line:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'dj.log'))
```

Then, in my job, I output to this log with:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger.info("Log Entry")
```

This results in the file `log/dj.log` being written to. This works in development, staging, and production environments.

Comment: Note `logger.debug` logs may be hidden by default depending on your setup, so I recommend using `logger.info` instead which is one level higher.