# Rails 4 - Delayed Job - Is it possible to know the Job id in the perform method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

Inside the `perform` method, I want to know what is the ID of the current job.

For instance, the `enqueue`, `success`, `failure` and `error` methods provide the `job` parameter:

```
def enqueue(job)
  puts job.id
end
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using sidekiq as a backend. In that case you may do the following:

```
def perform(*args)
  logger.info self.job_id
  # Do something later
end
```

Here is the log output

```
[ActiveJob] [RequestHandlerJob] [e9923650-cd02-40d1-937d-859852e92c61] e9923650-cd02-40d1-937d-859852e92c61
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, missed that.

I found solution in that [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632217/2244501)

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job.rb
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'dj.log'))


class RequestHandlerJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id)
    u = User.find(user_id)
    Delayed::Worker.logger.info self.job_id
    # Do something later
  end
end


[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/workspace/tapp/log]$ tail -f dj.log
I, [2016-06-24T07:58:32.329471 #23874]  INFO -- : 2016-06-24T07:58:32+0600: [Worker(host:iMac-Roman.local pid:23874)] Starting job worker
I, [2016-06-24T07:58:42.404522 #23874]  INFO -- : 2016-06-24T07:58:42+0600: [Worker(host:iMac-Roman.local pid:23874)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=7) RUNNING
I, [2016-06-24T07:58:42.448858 #23874]  INFO -- : 5f267272-8826-491d-b7d5-82a200e1a6b6
I, [2016-06-24T07:58:42.451204 #23874]  INFO -- : 2016-06-24T07:58:42+0600: [Worker(host:iMac-Roman.local pid:23874)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=7) COMPLETED after 0.0466
I, [2016-06-24T07:58:42.452007 #23874]  INFO -- : 2016-06-24T07:58:42+0600: [Worker(host:iMac-Roman.local pid:23874)] 1 jobs processed at 15.9642 j/s, 0 failed
```

Here is the job_id `5f267272-8826-491d-b7d5-82a200e1a6b6`. Hope that will help.

Comment: I am not sure if it still applies as I am using Rails 4.1.8 and the Delayed Job gem from https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: I added delayed_job example.

Comment: I guess I can't use ActiveJob::Base, as I am in rails 4.1.8 (not 4.2). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Could you please post your code we are talking about? In general there is the same approach for just delayed_job. You need to define logger in intializers and then you can find job id in it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was in an initializer, you can monkey patch the JobWrapper class and use

```
module ActiveJob
  module QueueAdapters
    class DelayedJobAdapter
      class JobWrapper
        def perform(job)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```