# See output from background task run with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

If I start my background worker for [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/7db56546f430f7a3b025dd96daa12c9207cbcdea), and then submit a job, the job runs but I do not see any terminal output from the job. How do I arrange it so I can see terminal output. I am using ruby on rails in development mode.

I want to do this when I when issue the command `bin/delayed_job start`.

Comment: You'll need to set up a logger. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631910/logging-in-delayed-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Gene and Shani, you can set up a logger by adding

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))
```

to `config/initializers/delayed_job_initializers.rb` and then in the running process output using

```
Delayed::Worker.logger.debug("Log Entry")
```

and then viewing the output using

```
tail -f log/delayed_job.log.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can start worker on a rails console. what I do when I want to debug delayed job is

```
worker = Delayed::Worker.new
worker.start
```

Comment: That could be useful, but the output from the job helps me monitor its progress, so I want to do this when issue the command ```bin/delayed_job start```

Comment: all the commands listed here https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Delayed-job-command-details

you can do set up logger as mentioned by user above and then use the tail command to see the log
tail -f log/delayed_job.log

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bin/rails jobs:work` command in a separate terminal window. It will start processing jobs in that terminal without exiting.

If you've put breakpoints or `puts` statements in your job, you'll see them in the terminal.

Stop the process using `CTRL-C`.

Hope that helps.