# Delayed_job_active_record sends mail succesffuly in rails console but not on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm using `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` for sending out emails. When my `SignupMailer` is called to send out an email , I see this in my console:

```
Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=23) RUNNING
```

But the job never completes.

However if I try calling my `SignupMailer` directly in rails console, the mail gets sent just fine. Help please?

My classes:

user.rb

```
def send_init_emails
    generate_token(:activation_token)
    SignupMailer.delay.welcome(self)
end
```

signup_mailer.rb:

```
def welcome(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome!'
end
```

Comment: Have you checked out error logs of DelayedJob? If so, share it.

Comment: @scaryguy does DelayJob log to development.rb by default? If so, there are no errors in there..

Comment: see `log/delayed_job.log` ?

Comment: the only files in the log directory are `development.rb` and `production.log`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183676/delayed-job-not-logging-in-production

Comment: All I see in the log is this
`2013-08-10T14:34:52-0700: [Worker(host:Pro.local pid:46266)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=25) RUNNING
2013-08-10T14:34:57-0700: [Worker(host:Pro.local pid:46266)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=26) RUNNING`

Comment: Add some `puts` messages inside your job file and see what is being executed and what is not.